# Video app is not working on 6.1

Tags: videos, video-player

After doing clean install Eos 6.1 to two laptops I saw that the video app is not opening.

Even if I click the icon nothing is happening. I checked to run this from terminal and I got the below error that I have in screenshot.
[image]

i also installed the ubuntu-restricted-extras to see if this fix the error but unfortunately I am getting the same error. The video app is not opening.
I didn't had this problem on 6.0 version. The problem is on the 6.1 version of EOS.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: [Edit] : an update fixed this issue. Im also having same issue.
no post either on this issue anywhere.
seems to be issue with Flatpak, Canberra module is not pulled while install by Flatpak.

Answer (score 1):

the two commands above:
`flatpak install io.elementary.video` and

```
flatpak install --system freedesktop org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default//20.08
```

doesn't work for me...
So I uninstalled the video from the app center, then we installed celloid with Faltpak (https://celluloid-player.github.io/installation.html)

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak install flathub io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid
```

and it worked on my computer...
The result is that Celluloid is installed and the Video app is also installed and working fine..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Elementary OS Videos couldn't play videos. I tried to debug the reason and launched via terminal:

```
flatpack run io.elementary.video
```

But there was no error in the terminal.
I tried installing various recommended codecs:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras libavcodec-extra libdvd.pkg
```

These measures couldn't help Videos.

So I downloaded Celluloid from AppCenter which weighed about 700MBytes and then removed Celluloid.
Voila. Videos runs flawlessly now.
I think the reason is the lack of multimedia codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Install io.elementary.video from flatpak daily

```
flatpak install io.elementary.video
```

then choose daily build
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its been reported that an update is missing from the stable version that is available already in the daily builds. Try adding this command:

```
 flatpak install --system freedesktop org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default//20.08
```

I've seen a few people report that fix worked for them in a Brazilian user group

Answer (score 0):

I am not a technical person,but the other OS worked nice
Would it be better just to forget os6
Can't be done with pissing about tbh

Answer (score 0):

Installing haruna player via flatpak works for me.